# Get the name of the webusercontrol in the intellisense, I have added reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webusercontrol

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ Reference Control = "CHEADER.ascx" Page="~/Default.aspx" %>
<%@ Reference Control = "CLEFT_NAVIGATION.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control = "CCOPYRIGHT.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control = "CBOTTOM_NAVIGATION.ascx" %>

<%@ Reference Control = "CPAGE0001.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control = "CPAGE0002.ascx" %>
<%@ Reference Control = "CPAGE0003.ascx" %>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WELCOME</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <table align="center" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="HEADER" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="LEFT_NAVIGATION" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="DETAILS" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="COPYRIGHT" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="BOTTOM_NAVIGATION" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                            <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### on .cs code behind i want to use the following code

if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
    WebUserControl1 uc = 
      (WebUserControl1) Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx"); 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc); 
}

### - but

none of the usercontrols appear thats is if i replace "WebUserControl1" by name CHEADER it says CHEADER? what is that!!

asp.net c# vsts2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Control details = LoadControl("WebUserControl.ascx");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(details);


    Control details1 = LoadControl("WebUserControl2.ascx");
    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(details1);



}
```

this works :-)

Answer (score 1):

try using register

```
<%@ Register Src="~/CHEADER.ascx" TagName="uc" TagPrefix="webcontrol" %>
```

Comment: it is added on run time by code, so i cannot place it on the page, or can i?

Comment: You can add... You just simply have to register the Usercontrol on top of the page on which you want to use it.